# Algorithm analysis , Big O Notation Homework

Tags: big-o

Hi can someone explain me how to resolve this homework?
(n + log n)3^n = O((4^n)/n).
i think it's the same as resolving this inequality: (n + log n)3^n < c((4^n)/n)).

thanks in advance

Comment: do you want an answer?  You won't get that here.  All you will get is perhaps some advice on how to approach it.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  Or just, *"Here's my homework, please do it for me?"*

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a c (as you mentioned in your problem), and you need to show that the inequality holds for all n greater than some k.

By showing that you can find the c and k in question, then [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) you've proved the big-O bound.

Conversely, if you can't find such a c and k, this is because the function on the left is not really upper-bounded by the function on the right. That shouldn't be the case here, though (and you'll know you're getting a more intuitive understanding of asymptotic growth/bounding when you can articulate exactly why).

Comment: .. i already knew this the problem is that i can't find the c an k parameters even though i know they exist , that why  i was asking for help

Answer (score 1):

By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), `f(n) = O(g(n))` is true if there exists a constant M such that `|f(n)| < M|g(n)|` for every n. In computer science, numbers are nonnegative, so this amounts to finding an M such that `f(n) / g(n) < M`

This, in turn, can be done by proving that `f(n) / g(n)` has a finite limit as `n` increases towards infinity (by definition of a limit). Which, in the case of your `(n^2 + n log n) * (3/4)^n` is pretty obvious by virtue of how exponential functions work.

Comment: you mean doing : lim n--> infinity of (n^2+nlogn)* 3^n / (4^n) ?